# Mediaplayer returns (-1, 1004) error while trying to read audio by url ,Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, audio

Good evening dear everyone, I use Android studio and recyclerview to display the list of audio recorded in Firebase storage. the audio recordings as well as their display in the recyclerview, went well but when it comes to playing the audio, it returns the error (-1, 1004). Also the link of my audio plays in chrome but when I try to play the link directly with setDataSource, the reading does not pass and returns me (-1, 1004). I tried to read this link http://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3 directly with setDataSource and it worked. Problem with Firebase audio links? most solutions propose to go to Exoplayer but I'm at the end of the project, it's the last thing I miss. Thanks for reacting

Voici une aperçu de mon code de lecture :
 public void play_songs() {
        mediaPlayer  = new MediaPlayer();

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                .build());

    } else {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    try {
        //

        // URL de test  : http://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3
        Toast.makeText(context, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("VERIFIONS link ", "CHANGEONS MESSAGE" + link);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(link);
        Log.d("APRES SETSOURCE ", "APRES SETSOURCE" );
        //mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        Log.d("APRES PREPARE ASYNC", "APRES PREPARE ASYNC" );
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //seekbar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                int tailleduseekbarre = mp.getDuration();
                Log.d("DANS ON PREPARE", "DANS ON PREPARE" );
                mp.start();
                Log.d("APRES MP START ", "APRES MP START" );

                Log.d(" TAG DURATION", " VRIFIONS LA DUREE " + mp.getDuration());
                Log.d(" TAG tailleduseekbar", " VRIFIONS LA DUREE tailleduseekbar" + tailleduseekbarre);

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, " Media player Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });


        PlayCycle();

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);

                    //CurrentTimer.setText(progress);

                    //Log.d(" AFFICHE", "PROGRSSIONS"+ String.valueOf(progress));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Prepare failed.: status", " ALORS" + equals(e.getMessage()));
        Log.d("Catch De play song", "message " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I got the audio links by doing:

```
private void UploadFile(){
    int mtn = i++ ;
    final StorageReference ref2 = storageReference.child("/Audio/").child(audionamePlus);

     Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(outputfile));
    ref2.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(FriendList.this, "Vocal saved into db storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ref2.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                    String oui = getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: uri= " + uri.toString());
                    String link = uri.toString();
                    //String audioname = "audio2.mp3";
                    DocumentReference docRef2 = db.collection("AUDIO CHAT").document(oui);
                    String doId = docRef2.getId();
                    Log.d(" TAG DURATION2", " VRIFIONS LA DUREE22 " + tailleduseekbarre);
                    Audio_modele audio = new Audio_modele(doId, audionamePlus, elapsedMillis, link, tailleduseekbarre);
                    AudioHelper.getAudioCollection().add(audio).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText(FriendList.this, " SAVE ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

Help !!

[image]

Comment: You need to first prepare download url from your firebase storage and then use that to play media.

Comment: Follow the documentation, here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: Thanks for the orientation. I will refer to it ... for a moment

Comment: I think that's what I did in my UploadFile method. After having obtained the link, I save it. Now, in the class to recycle it, I recover the link according to the position of the audio to choose. Look ..

Comment: @Rahul Shukla, you are there, the problem still persists